# How to use .otf font file as math font in XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, mathspec

I'm using mathspec to use an `.otf` font in Overleaf via the command:

`setromanfont{myfont}[Path=./fonts/myfont, Extension = .otf, Uprightfont=*-regular]`

`myfont-regular.otf` being the font file placed in a folder pointed at by the `Path=`.

which works great for all my normal text. However there is also a math version of the font that I would like to use for math: `myfont-math.otf` however I cannot find a way to import it with the mathspec package, all my attempts at using the `\setmath(s)font` have been futile. I've looked around and found some articles from Overleaf with instructions of how to use a `.ttf` font with `tfm/map/type1` files but not much so far on how to do this is XeLaTeX. It might help to mention that I have all these files for my font as it has been designed to work with TeX.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction of how to do this?

Comment: if the math font is an opentype math font with a MATH table, use `unicode-math` rather than `mathspec`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I looked up the difference between mathspec and unicode-math and got the impression that they were mostly identical packages which led me down the wrong path.

Comment: For reference, David Carlisle has an example how to use otf font with mathspec here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650190/250119

Answer (score 1):

If the math font is an opentype math font with a MATH table, use `unicode-math` rather than `mathspec`.

Comment: is it possible to check if the font has a MATH table in it?

Comment: @Masum look in a font editor such as fontforge or simply use the font with `\setmathfont` in unicode-math package, it will complain about it not being there. If the font hasn't got "math" in its name, it probably has not got a math table.